# MeshData GetVertexData has the incorrect length

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to optimize some mesh generation using MeshData & the Job System, but for some reason when I try to use 2 params in `meshData.SetVertexBufferParams`, the resulting `meshData.GetVertexData` is half the length it should be (I set the vertex count to 5120, but the resulting VertexData NativeArray is only 2560 items long). 
When I force it to be double the length (`SetVertexBufferParams(numVerts * 2, ...)`), it creates a mesh that appears to treat the norms and vert positions as all position data and also makes the screen go black so no screen shot.

Here's my code:

```cs
// generate 256 height values
int[] arr = new int[256];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = (int) (Mathf.PerlinNoise(i / 16 / 16f, i % 16 / 16f) * 5);
}
// put it in a NativeArray
NativeArray<int> heights = new NativeArray<int>(arr, Allocator.TempJob);

// 4 verts per face * 5 faces = 20
int numVerts = heights.Length * 20; // this value is always 5120
// 2 tris per face * 5 daces * 3 indices = 30
int indices = heights.Length * 30;

// MeshData setup
Mesh.MeshDataArray meshDataArray = Mesh.AllocateWritableMeshData(1);
Mesh.MeshData meshData = meshDataArray[0];
meshData.SetVertexBufferParams(numVerts,
    new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Position, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3, stream:0),
    new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Normal, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3, stream:1)
);
meshData.SetIndexBufferParams(indices, IndexFormat.UInt16);

// Create job
Job job = new Job
{
    Heights = heights,
    MeshData = meshData
};
// run job
job.Schedule().Complete();
```

```cs
// struct I'm using for vertex data
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct VData
{
    public float3 Vert;
    public float3 Norm;
}

// Here's some parts of the job
public struct Job : IJob
{
    [ReadOnly]
    public NativeArray<int> Heights;
    public Mesh.MeshData MeshData;

    public void Execute()
    {
        NativeArray<VData> Verts = MeshData.GetVertexData<VData>();
        NativeArray<ushort> Tris = MeshData.GetIndexData<ushort>();

        // loops from 0 to 255
        for (int i = 0; i < Heights.Length; i++)
        {
            ushort t1 = (ushort)(w1 + 16);


            // This indicates that Verts.Length is 2560 when it should be 5120
            Debug.Log(Verts.Length);

            int t = i * 30; // tris
            int height = Heights[i];
            // x and y coordinate in chunk
            int x = i / 16;
            int y = i % 16;

            float3 up = new float3(0, 1, 0);

            // This throws and index out of bounds error because t1 becomes larger than Verts.Length
            Verts[t1] = new VData { Vert = new float3(x + 1, height, y + 1), Norm = up};

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahah yeah I'm just using that for test data. Once the mesh generation is done I'll make a seperate burst job for heightmap generation, but thanks for saving me the effort of finding something faster than PerlinNoise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
meshData.SetVertexBufferParams(numVerts,
    new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Position, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3, stream:0),
    new VertexAttributeDescriptor(VertexAttribute.Normal, VertexAttributeFormat.Float32, 3, stream:1)
);
```

Your `SetVertexBufferParams` here places `VertexAttribute.Position` and `VertexAttribute.Normal` on a separate `stream`s thus halving the size of the buffer **per stream** and later the length of the buffers if buffer becomes reinterpreted with the wrong `struct` by mistake.

This is how [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.VertexAttributeDescriptor.html) explains streams:

> Vertex data is laid out in separate "`stream`s" (each `stream` goes into a separate vertex buffer in the underlying graphics API). While Unity supports up to 4 vertex `stream`s, most meshes use just one. Separate `stream`s are most useful when some vertex attributes don't need to be processed, for example skinned meshes often use two vertex `stream`s (one containing all the skinned data: positions, normals, tangents; while the other `stream` contains all the non-skinned data: colors and texture coordinates).

But why it might end up re-interpreted as half the length? Well, because of this line:

> `NativeArray<VData> Verts = MeshData.GetVertexData<VData>();`

How? Because there is a implicit `stream` parameter value there ([doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.MeshData.GetVertexData.html))

> `public NativeArray<T> GetVertexData(int stream = 0);`

and it defaults to `0`. So what happens here is this:

`var Verts = Positions_Only.Reinterpret<Position_And_Normals>();`

or in other words:

`var Verts = NativeArray<float3>().Reinterpret<float3x2>();`

*case solved :T*

#### TL;DR:

- Change `stream:1` to `stream:0` so both vertex attributes end up on the same stream.
- **or** `var Positions = MeshData.GetVertexData<float3>(0);` & `var Normals = MeshData.GetVertexData<float3>(1);`
- **or** create a dedicated `VData` struct per stream `var Stream0 = MeshData.GetVertexData<VStream0>(0);` & `var Stream1 = MeshData.GetVertexData<VStream1>(1);`

Comment: Ah, I completely misunderstood the point of streams. Thanks for the thorough explanation!